# Intellij 2017.1.1 "Show Diff with Local" to compare git commit with local changes disabled for folders

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Since the latest update to Intellij 2017.1.1 I have been unable to compare a git commit to the local codebase in Intellij. This option does work if I view the git history for a single file and then right click on a commit in the history, but not when I view the git history for a folder with multiple files, then this option is disabled when right clicking on a commit.

This used to work in previous versions of Intellij. Has the feature I am looking for moved or can this be achieved in another way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that has already been fixed. Will work correctly in next update.
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171150